# How can I attach a view/pdf/xml in an Email? Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I want to send and email like this:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('bla bla')
        ->setFrom('example@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('example@gmail.com')
        ->setCharset('UTF-8')
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setBody("hi");


    $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
    $output->writeln('sent!');
```

However, I want attach a generate template like this:

```
$template = $this->getContainer()->get('templating');    
$xml = $template->render("MrLibrariesReportsBundle:Transactions:download.xml.twig", $viewData);
```

I tried to do:

```
    $message->attach($xml);
```

But it doesnt work.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it. I did the next code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('bla bla')
        ->setFrom('example@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('example@gmail.com')
        ->setCharset('UTF-8')
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setBody("hi")
        ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attach));


$this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
$output->writeln('sent!');
```

$attach is the patch of file or in this case is the render of template:

```
$template = $this->getContainer()->get('templating');    
$xml = $template->render("MrLibrariesReportsBundle:Transactions:download.xml.twig", $viewData);
```

> $attach == $xml

The most important is:

> \Swift_Attachment::

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Subject')
            ->setFrom('From')
            ->setTo('To')
            ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render(
                'AppBundle:Mail:welcome.html.twig', $viewData),
                'text/html'
            );
$this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: Umm no because you setBody I want  attach a xml which is generated in $xml like this: [IMG](http://www.dryant.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/2013218-email.png)

Comment: @SergioHerreroCruz oh then in that case:  http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content